# MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification issue - iOS8 - swift

Tags: swift, ios8, mpmovieplayercontroller, nsnotificationcenter

I've implement a MPMoviePlayerViewController, that load the video and dismiss the player correctly. But I can't get notify when user tap "Done" in **MPMoviePlayerViewController**. 
I think it's an ios8 problem. This is the code:

```
func fullscreenVideo(){
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "doneFull:", name: MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification, object: nil)

    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: self.videoPath)
    self.fullscreenPlayer = MPMoviePlayerViewController(contentURL: url)        
    self.fullscreenPlayer!.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 0.0, height: 0.0)
    self.fullscreenPlayer!.moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 0.0, height: 0.0)
    self.fullscreenPlayer!.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.Fullscreen
    self.fullscreenPlayer!.moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatMode.One
    self.fullscreenPlayer!.moviePlayer.allowsAirPlay = false
    self.fullscreenPlayer!.moviePlayer.fullscreen = true
    self.fullscreenPlayer!.moviePlayer.prepareToPlay()
    self.presentViewController(self.fullscreenPlayer!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    self.fullscreenPlayer!.moviePlayer.play()
}

func doneFull(notification:NSNotification){
    // When user tap "Done" the player closes but this function is not called.
    println("CALLED") // Never called
}
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, 
selector: "doneFull:", 
name: MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification, 
object: self.fullscreenPlayer!.moviePlayer)
```

try replace your object nil with **self.fullscreenPlayer!.moviePlayer**

you have to set object parameter in this case.